# Docker memory limits not respected by mongo

Tags: mongodb, unix, docker, memory, memory-management

I am experiencing issue where mongodb does not respect imposed container memory limits and spills over into swap and slows to a crawl - the issue seems to be that mongo thinks all host memory is available to it. See https://github.com/dockerfile/mongodb/issues/34

My question is then - how does docker implement memory limits? I don't really have a big picture understanding of what the available options are for restricting resource access like this in unix - would someone be able to give a quick overview?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

There are a few points here.

First, any process running in your container will believe that it has access to as much memory as your host has (docker does not virtualize memory)

You can limit the memory your container is authorized to use by setting the parameter `--memory`. You can disable swap by setting `--memory-swap` to the exact same value as `--memory`:

> If --memory and --memory-swap are set to the same value, this prevents containers from using any swap. This is because --memory-swap is the amount of combined memory and swap that can be used, while --memory is only the amount of physical memory that can be used.

Now, remember that even if you set --memory and --memory-swap, your application (mongoDB) will believe it has access to the total memory of your host system. In mongoDb 3.2, it will use 60% of your total memory, minus 1G. If you want to limit this, you need to configure `storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB`

> storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB: The maximum size of the internal cache that WiredTiger will use for
>   all data.

Check the mongoDB documentation here: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/#storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB

And the docker documentation:
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#memory

Comment: Right, uh, I did read the docs... 

When I say "imposed container memory limits" in the post I mean `--memory`. 

That is just wiredtiger, mongo also has a filesystem cache and uses all available memory for it with no way to disable it.

Comment: Filesystem cache is not going to cause swap issues. At worst, it will evict other pages in the filesystem cache used by other applications.

Comment: Well, hypothetically. The docker docs also say that mongo should never fail in the way which it continues to, where it spills into swap and grinds to a halt.

Comment: Can you share the way you configure your docker mem and mongodb? At the moment I assume you only set --memory. Docker configuration says: "If --memory-swap is unset, and --memory is set, the container can use twice as much swap as the --memory setting".

Comment: You are picking nits with irrelevant details - the mongo docs clearly state that under no circumstances will mongo *ever* spill over into swap and slow to a crawl like this. The problem is that mongo thinks it still has access to the totality of host memory

Comment: Can you share the mongoDB link where it states that "under no circumstances will mongo ever spill over into swap?" If you don't share the way you  configure docker and mogodb, it will be hard for me or someone else to hep you.  As a side note, using a friendly tone is typically a good strategy to get free help from other members. You might not realize it, but your tone is not ideal to encourage people to help you.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what has already been specified in previous answers, Mongodb will respect the container memory setting from versions 3.6.13 and 4.0.9:

> `hostInfo.system.memLimitMB`
>
> The memory usage limit in megabytes.
>
> For example, running in a container may impose memory limits that are
> lower than the total system memory. This memory limit, rather than the
> total system memory, is used as the maximum RAM available to calculate
> WiredTiger internal cache.
>
> Available starting in MongoDB 4.0.9 (and 3.6.13)

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/hostInfo/#hostInfo.system.memLimitMB